# How to find duplicate values in only one column while using a where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

At the moment I have a select query finding an X amount of emails in my customer database and returning something like this

```
SELECT
 first_name,
 last_name,
 email_address,
 date_deleted
FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE email_address in ('bob.smith@gmail.com', 'john.green@gmail.com', 'simon.anderson@gmail.com', 'carl.thomas@gmail.com');

+----+------------+-----------+---------------------------+--------------+
| id | first_name | last_name | email_address             | date_deleted |
+----+------------+-----------+---------------------------+--------------+
|  1 | bob        | smith     | bob.smith@gmail.com       | 2013-02-18   |
|  2 | NULL       | NULL      | bob.smith@gmail.com       | NULL         |
|  3 | john       | green     | john.green@gmail.com      | NULL         |
|  4 | simon      | anderson  | simon.anderson@gmail.com  | NULL         |
|  5 | carl       | thomas    | carl.thomas@gmail.com     | 2012-09-20   |
|  6 | NULL       | NULL      | carl.thomas@gmail.com     | NULL         |
+----+------------+-----------+---------------------------+--------------+
```

In the email address column, there are duplicate email addresses. I would like to modify my query so it returns the duplicates in only that column and filtered through the date_deleted.  Is this possible?

```
+----+------------+-----------+---------------------------+--------------+
| id | first_name | last_name | email_address             | date_deleted |
+----+------------+-----------+---------------------------+--------------+
|  1 | bob        | smith     | bob.smith@gmail.com       | 2013-02-18   |
|  2 | carl       | thomas    | carl.thomas@gmail.com     | 2012-09-20   |
+----+------------+-----------+---------------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: So you just want to find all the records that have duplicate emails? In that case you might wanna look at HAVING clause

Comment: Why does the Carl Thomas duplicate record have null names while Bob Smith has this data?

Comment: I made an edit to my question, as to why there are null names, that's the kind of data there is in the real database

Comment: @MikeTung I tried a HAVING clause but it just showed the number of duplicates, i need the query to return like the above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to find duplicated values in a column is to use the HAVING statement, as Mike Tung mentioned in his comment.

```
SELECT email_address
  FROM CUSTOMERS
 GROUP BY email_address
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

This will give you back the following results:

```
+---------------------------+
| email_address             |
+---------------------------+
| bob.smith@gmail.com       |
| carl.thomas@gmail.com     |
+---------------------------+
```

You can then do whatever other logic you need to with the results from this query. If I am understanding your question correctly, you are wanting to find records with duplicated email addresses that also have a non-null date_deleted. If so, you can get that information with the following query:

```
SELECT CUS.first_name
       ,CUS.last_name
       ,CUS.email_address
       ,CUS.date_deleted
  FROM CUSTOMERS AS CUS
  JOIN (SELECT email_address
          FROM CUSTOMERS
         GROUP BY email_address
        HAVING COUNT(1) > 1) AS C
       ON C.email_address = CUS.email_address
 WHERE CUS.date_deleted IS NOT NULL
```

This should give you the results:

```
+----+------------+-----------+---------------------------+--------------+
| id | first_name | last_name | email_address             | date_deleted |
+----+------------+-----------+---------------------------+--------------+
|  1 | bob        | smith     | bob.smith@gmail.com       | 2013-02-18   |
|  2 | carl       | thomas    | carl.thomas@gmail.com     | 2012-09-20   |
+----+------------+-----------+---------------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: @Sai that was what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with MySQL

```
SELECT 
 first_name,
 last_name,
 email_address,
 date_deleted
FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE email_address in ('bob.smith@gmail.com', 'john.green@gmail.com', 'simon.anderson@gmail.com', 'carl.thomas@gmail.com') 
GROUP BY email_address
HAVING COUNT(email_address) > 1
```